# Kendo grid filter mode row with boolean

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with data which have a `boolean` type.
I use the filter mode 'row'.

I use a `combobox` for the filter like that:

```
filterable: {
  cell: {
    template: function (args) {
      args.element.kendoComboBox({

        valuePrimitive: true,
        dataSource: [
          { text: "No", value: "false" },
          { text: "Yes", value: "true" },
          { text: "All", value: "all" }
        ],
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value"
      });

    },
    operator: "eq",
    showOperators: false
  }
}
```

The dojo sample : http://dojo.telerik.com/@lgoubet/uGeYIXoG

I don't want to use

```
filterable: {
    messages:
    {
      isTrue: "Oui",
      isFalse: "Non"
    }
}
```

I would like use a checkbox or radio button because it's prettier
and more appropriate.

Do you have a sample? An idea?

Comment: Could you give us a complete verifiable example in a fiddle or dojo?

Comment: here you are http://dojo.telerik.com/@lgoubet/uGeYIXoG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom filter with any element you want. and onChange event of your element trigger the filter:

Here is an example:

```
 $('#yourRadio').change(function (ev) {
        var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
        var field = 'Locked';
        var operator = 'contains';
        var value = this.value;
        grid.dataSource.filter({
            field: field,
            operator: operator,
            value: value
        });
    });
```

You also can deactivate of remove the filters on the head section of your grid with CSS.

```
th [role="listbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;
}   
thead {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kendo provides an automatic boolean filter, you just have to tell it that "locked" is a boolean by specifying it in the DataSource [schema](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schemamodel):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        data: data,
        schema: {
            model: {
            fields: {
              locked: {
                type: "boolean"
              },
              name: {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
   ...});
```

Full sample here: http://dojo.telerik.com/aGOvOYiT

Now whether that filter is what you want (it's two radio buttons) is a UX question more than a Kendo one. I'd advise against one checkbox, since it's unclear whether the unchecked state means "not filtered" or "filtered by false". Your combobox is a nice solution, since it has 3 clear and distinct states.

Comment: ok thanks I didn't see when the filter clear the radio button are unchecked